# How to push for a real company culture?

Tags: company-culture

I'm new in my company and I'm also the youngest (23 years old).

The CEO is trying to hire more young graduates as software engineers, and has asked me how to attract them. I know that some friends of my weren't interested in the company because of the lack of company culture.

How can I create a company culture and have it adopted by current employees?

The company is pretty small (30 people) and is already a bit old (20 years).

Comment: "because of the lack of company culture" - can you be more precise on what was lacking (e.g. company events, etc.). Company culture is not something you can simply have or not have. If you search for the term on this site the questions usually deal with something more specific.

Comment: A bit of everything: company events, work environment a bit old, no global methodology for different projects,... In fact the company is a "classical company" in the tech domain, that doesn't seem fun at all.

Comment: All companies have a company culture. Some just have bad ones, but none are more "real" than others.

Comment: You don't create a company culture. Tell the CEO what kind of culture would attract more young graduates.

Comment: Personally I would avoid a "Fun" company culture at all costs. Those are teh businesses in my experience that are most likely to  fail because business isn't about having fun, it is about making money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few years ago I worked for a company that promoted a relaxed work environment. We had table tennis in the office, pub every friday, beers on your birthday. That all started from the boss wanting to do those things, and the staff wanted to take part too.

Fast forward a few years, new employer. The bosses wanted to promote the image of fun for the clients. They organised activity days for the clients and the staff to bond. Barbeques, quad-biking, paintball, etc. Again, this started because of an image that the company wanted to promote and the staff were offered the chance to join in.

Essentially, a lot of the culture stems from the company spending money on things, someone leading the charge and getting the staff on board. Without all three of those things, you're not going to change the cultrue.